# Add item in listview arrayadapter

Tags: android

Please tell me how to add items in listview arrayadapter?
I found only how to make for standard adapter

Activity:

```
public class Activity extends Activity { 
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.m);

        ListView lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv); 
        String[] Id1={"1","2","3"}, Text1={"one","two","three"}; 

        CustomAdapter ad = new CustomAdapter(this, Id1 , Text1); 
        ad.setCustomListener(new LVListener() { 
            public void onClick(String text) { 
                Log.d("APP", text); 
            } 
        }); 
        lv.setAdapter(ad);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn); 
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View view) { 
                btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                String[] Id2={"4","5","6"},Text2={"four","five","six"}; 
                // add Id2 and Text2 in listview
            } 
        }); 
    } 
}
```

CustomAdapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> { 
    private final Context context; 
    private final String[] id, text; 
    private ListViewListener micl;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] id, String[] text) { 
        super(context, R.layout.list, id); 
        this.context = context; 
        this.id = id; 
        this.text = text; 
    }

    public void setCustomListener(ListViewListener micl) { this.micl = micl; }

    @Override 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        View View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);

        final int pos = position;
        final TextView tView = (TextView) View.findViewById(R.id.textView); 
        tView.setText(text[pos]);

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                if (micl != null)
                    micl.onClick(text[pos]);
            } 
        });
        return View; 
    } 
}
```

I tried to do with notifyDatasetChanged() but nothing happened.
Please tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayAdapter` has the [add](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#add%28T%29) method, but in order to use it the dataset you provide to the super can not be an array, that's because the using `Arrays.asList(objects)`, that returns an immutable list. From the documentation

> Returns a List of the objects in the specified array. The size of the
>   List cannot be modified, i.e. adding and removing are unsupported, but
>   the elements can be set. Setting an element modifies the underlying
>   array.